# savon soap request execution expired

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

I have a very simple ruby script that looks like this:

```
require 'savon'  

client = Savon::Client.new do
  wsdl.document = "http://server/app/app.svc?wsdl"
end
```

If I then do something like:

```
client.wsdl.operations
```

I get all of the operations from my service, so it is connecting and retrieving the wsdl correctly.

However, if I try to run an operation

```
response = client.request "Test"
```

I get "HTTPClient::ReceiveTimeoutError: execution expired"
I am also looking at Fiddler, and don't see that any request was even made.
I have confirmed the service works correctly through other technologies (C#, JS)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: your code should send a request. i'd need more information about your service to help out. let me know if there's a way to access that service.

Comment: @rubiii unfortunately there's not. But at least I know there's nothing wrong with the Ruby code. Thanks.

Comment: you could try using another http client. savon uses [httpi](https://github.com/rubiii/httpi) to execute http request. trying net/http or curb might help you isolate the problem.

Comment: look at the readme. try `HTTPI.adapter = :curb` or `HTTPI.adapter = :net_http`.

Comment: Installing the curb gem and using the curb setting in rubiii's comment did the trick for me.  Thanks!